# Perl OO frameworks and program design - Moose and Conway's inside-out objects (Class::Std)

Tags: perl, class, moose, oop

This is more of a use-case type of question... but also generic enough to be more broadly applicable:

In short, I'm working on a module that's more or less a command-line wrapper;  OO naturally.  Without going into too many details (unless someone wants them), there isn't a crazy amount of complexity to the system, but it did feel natural to have three or four objects in this framework. Finally, it's an open source thing I'll put out there, rather than a module with a few developers in the same firm working on it.

First I implemented the OO using Class::Std, because Perl Best Practices (Conway, 2005) made a good argument for why to use inside-out objects.  Full control over what attributes get accessed and so on, proper encapsulation, etc.  Also his design is surprisingly simple and clever.

I liked it, but then noticed that no one really uses this;  in fact it seems Conway himself doesn't really recommend this anymore?

So I moved to everyone's favorite, Moose.  It's easy to use, although way way overkill feature-wise for what I want to do.  The big, major downside is:  it's got a slew of module dependencies that force users of my module to download them all.  A minor downside is it's got way more functionality than I really need.

What are recommendations?  Inconvenience fellow developers by forcing them to use a possibly-obsolete module, or force every user of the module to download Moose and all its dependencies?

Is there a third option for a proper Perl OO framework that's popular but neither of these two?

Comment: Define "slew"? Moose has 4 dependencies not in Class::Std, of those the largest is Class::MOP which is the whole point of Moose.

Comment: You're forgetting the dependencies of the dependencies. :-)

Comment: A slew -> http://deps.cpantesters.org/?module=Moose;perl=latest  Discounting all the core modules, 16 isn't that bad, but its not 4.

Comment: And the greatest thing is, Moose is so standard now that your Linux Distribution should have it available in their core repository, and that /may/ make a sysadmins job a bit easier.

Comment: ( As opposed to Class::Std  that is, which my distribution neither ships, nor do I have it, or anything that uses it installed )

Answer (score 5):

To be perfectly fair, seeing virtually everything interesting these days in Perl world has Moose somewhere as a dependency, I don't see it being much a debt for other "fellow Perl developers".

Chances are they already have it installed as we speak!

Edit: Some statistics:

Moose is currently rated at 65th place on the "Most Depended on" modules list, [Aliases top 100](http://ali.as/top100/), with over 1637 packages depending on it. Thats almost as much as stuff like `Time::HiRes` , and more than `DBI`, and I don't think you're as likely to question depending on those would you?

Comment: The module being written isn't geared toward hard-core developers, but to sys admins and the like.  It's a command-line wrapper / automation system of sorts.  If anything Moose is perhaps favorable for developers, but a PITA for people who have to install its dependencies.

Comment: Mouse, Moose minus the antlers, is *very* light on dependencies, and is optionally compiled from XS.

Comment: Also, Alias's list got a little Moose-heavy due to the adding of DBIx-Class's (optional) dependencies on Moose* modules being added to the META.yml for that project.

Comment: Mouse comes with fewer dependencies, but a lot more bugs and a lot less testing.

Comment: @jrockway Mouse copies the Moose test suite and then adds to it. While it doesn't pass them all, it knows what it can and cannot do (see the `failing` directories) and its very well tested.

Comment: People show up on #moose with bugs all the time.  After 15 minutes of debugging, we find that the problem is that they're using Mouse.  This happens enough for me to believe that it's not tested enough -- people come up with weird corner cases and fix them in Moose.  With Mouse, you're the first person to ever do that.  For many values of "that".

Answer (score 5):

The currently accepted "modern Perl OO framework" is Moose.  I'd say make your users download it, or you can bundle it up with your modules in the installation using [PAR::Packer](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PAR).

Quoting from "[But I can't use CPAN](http://www.shadowcat.co.uk/blog/matt-s-trout/but-i-cant-use-cpan/)" (...because my users won't want to install things):

> Assuming you're just handling your users a tarball, then Module::Install  provides a solution - if you put your script into script/ and then do
>
> ```
> install_script(glob 'script/*');
> auto_install;
> ```
>
> in your Makefile.PL, then not only will 'make install' put your script somewhere useful for you but 'make installdeps' will invoke cpan (or if present, cpanplus) to install all missing dependencies for you.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there's [Mouse](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mouse), which is like [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) but without all the dependencies (and some of the features).  It also starts up a bit faster.  I haven't tried it myself, but it's generally [well thought of](http://cpanratings.perl.org/d/Mouse).

Comment: Moose  is wonderful. Use Moose instead of Mouse.  # line 1 under "Description"

Comment: Yes, use Moose to develop your app, but use Mouse when you deploy it, especially since it is a command-line app, something that would benefit from the performance improvements of Mouse.  Look to Any::Moose.

Comment: No, don't do that.  Never use Any::Moose.

Comment: @jrockway And don't ever wear blue shirts with socks! Or drink coffee with 2% milk, it must be whole or half and half! (Uhh, rationale?)

Comment: I'm thinking `Mouse` gets more shit than my CPAN contributions.

Comment: Because Any::Moose leads people to believe that Mouse is just a better implementation of Moose.  It's not -- it has fewer features, a smaller community, fewer extensions, and lower runtime performance.  It's a simple hack to make an application like "cat" run from the commandline faster.

Answer (score 4):

To add to the existing fine answers...

Some of what was recommended in PBP isn't bad advice, but Perl marches on.  When it was written, inside-out objects were the new hotness.  Now the Moose has absorbed all.  There is [MooseX::InsideOut](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MooseX-InsideOut) which gives you the power of Moose with the total encapsulation of Class::Std, but unless you work with undisciplined programmers its really not necessary.

Those features of Moose you don't need now, you'll need them eventually.  Even if you don't need all of them, with Moose you won't have to use and learn Yet Another OO System every time you need an interesting feature.  And god forbid you need TWO features at the SAME TIME!

Comment: There are some applications where it is necessary that have nothing to do with "undisciplined programmers"

Comment: @Evan Avoiding private key clashes with subclasses comes to mind. What were you thinking of?

Comment: ... Filehandles, or any other obscure object that can be blessed but probably shouldn't and can't attach data to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a Perl Module Object::InsideOut , actively maintained as of 2010.

Kind of a predecessor to Moose, or to be clear: development started independently  at the same time as Moose started,

I know it exists but I haven't used it.